# Debian 8 Synaptic issue

Tags: debian, gcc, debian-installer, synaptic

I have a Debian 8 installed with its GCC4.8, and need to install GCC6, too.

Using Synaptic, if I select GCC6 from the list of installable packages, I get a message of this kind:

```
Mark additional required changes?
To be removed:
clang
g++
g++4.9
gnome
part of kde
libreoffice
...
```

Of course there must be something wrong in what I did. How can I simply install a new compiler without all these side effects?

Comment: In order to have both versions installed you should install GCC6 manually by compiling it and not through Synaptic.

Comment: What did you do to make GCC 6 available in Synaptic? (What repositories did you add?)

Comment: @StephenKitt: I added this line to /etc/apt/sources.list:  `deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian testing main contrib`

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio: I suppose the same applies to Ubuntu, right?

Comment: I agree I would not install from `testing`, just because you want the latest version of a package. You maybe able to get it via a `tar`.

Comment: @Pietro Correct, it also applies to Ubuntu.

Comment: Another way is to use dbootstrap, to install a minimal debian into a subdirectory. You can then use container (virtualisation) / chroot.

Comment: @richard: Should I download and build it from source? Is there any other repository I can get it from, built for Debian 8? Containers are not an option in my case.

Comment: According to the GNU website (https://gcc.gnu.org/svn.html): `svn checkout svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/tags/tagname gcc` e.g. `svn checkout svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/tags/gcc_6_3_0_release gcc` I think that the `gcc` at the end is the directory that it puts it into.

Comment: @richard: that line is to get the source, isn't it?

Comment: Yes that will check the source out of gnu's subversion repository. Then read the readme, it will tell you to do, if I remember correct: `./configure; make; sudo make install` I would recommend, using options to configure (that I can never remember), to set the install root to `/usr/local` instead of `/usr`. Only `apt` should put stuff in `/usr/`, `/bin`, etc. `/usr/local` has directories for `lib`, `bin`, `var`, `etc` etc (always put staff that you (as opposed to apt) install in `/usr/local` or `/opt`)

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I built it from source.

AFAIK, installers can only deal with standard, predefined, locations for the executables, and if you need multiple versions of the same tools, you had better build then in /usr/local/.